# How to solve the anchor certificate expired?

Tags: certificates

Certificate (server.cer, will expire on January 1, 2017) put in the Bundle, the server after the renewal, if the user doesn't update App, he cannot access the server normally.

Access the server with anchor certificate, certificate expires in the application cannot be normal visit, now has the following solutions:

Set the certificate time: `SecTrustSetVerifyDate (trust: SecTrust,verifyDate:CFDate)`

The application of the certificate expires force users to update.
Do you have a better solution?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot figure out exactly what you're asking here - can you expand and clarify?   You've got a server with a server certificate that expires on January 1st, 2017. You are wondering what to do about that?  You should replace the certificate with a new one.  Is this a self-signed certificate situation and the clients have the public key for that cert and you're worried about having to update the clients? If that's the case, then yes, you'll have to update the server cert and install the public key in the clients. You can limit what you need to update if you use proper cert practices

Comment: Proper cert practices means having a root cert with a very long life that is kept very safe and whose public key is trusted by the clients, an intermediate cert that has a shorter lifespan and server keys that are signed by the intermediate cert.  You then install the keychain and the server key on the server.  I can expand if this is responsive to your question